# node sha256 convert to java

Tags: java, node.js, node-modules, cryptojs

I am trying to convert a library to java. I am stuck at one place.

This method in node js

```
import { SHA256, enc } from 'crypto-js'
export const sha256 = (hex) => {
  let hexEncoded = enc.Hex.parse(hex)
  return SHA256(hexEncoded).toString()
}
```

Can you please help it converting in java?
This is not directly sha256 encryption. 
for example :

```
Direct conversion : 
String : 68656c6c6f
Sha256 string : 4ef79bf561cdeacd465e135a3b9c8b51a42ded0605f15ab8e501162d2693bd00
```

Source : http://md5decrypt.net/en/Sha256/#answer

Above method conversion

```
String : 68656c6c6f
Sha256 String : 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
```

I am not sure what part i am missing. The first step is to convert it decimal array.But couldn't figure out the logic in second step.This is taken from crypto-js library.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

Comment: Hey @akash ? Were you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
String : 68656c6c6f
```

is basically the hex of String `hello` and

```
Sha256 String : 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
```

is the sha256 hash of `hello`

So first you need to parse String from Hex i.e ->

```
68656c6c6f -> hello
```

and then calculate the sha256 hash :->

```
hello -> 2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824
```

The Java Implementation for the same :->

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class libraryTransfer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DecoderException {
        String input = "hello";
        System.out.println("Hex from String :-> " + toHex(input));
        System.out.println("String from hex : -> " + getStringFromHex(toHex(input.trim())).trim());
        String sha256hex = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex(getStringFromHex(toHex(input)));
        System.out.println(sha256hex);
    }

    public static String toHex(String arg) {
        return Hex.encodeHexString(arg.getBytes(/* charset */));
    }

    public static String getStringFromHex(String inputHex) throws DecoderException {
        byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(inputHex.toCharArray());
        return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

}
```